# How to retrieve accumulator in Flink streaming?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have followed steps in this below link to achieve accumulator

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/user_defined_functions/#accumulators--counters

But after 3rd step to retrieve this

```
myJobExecutionResult.getAccumulatorResult("num-lines");
```

If it was a batch job I can implement FlinkListener and override onJobExecuted and use "myJobExecutionResult", But in streaming approach from where I can get myJobExeuctionResult? Can anyone help me with example snippets?

Answer (score 2):

An example of how to use accumulators in Apache Flink can be found in this recipe on Session Windows in the Immerok Cookbook: https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/using-session-windows/

(Note: I work for Immerok)